# Nifi gmail open source jdbc driver

Tags: jdbc, gmail, apache-nifi

I have been trying to send mail from the nifi PutEmail processor using the gmail account credentials. Is there any opensource gmail jdbc driver that can be used as an alternate of cData jdbc driver. I fail to find one.

Comment: why do you need JDBC driver for gmail when there is send/receive email is present in nifi?

Comment: The error shows the No class definition found. Could you share if you have an example that I can use? For me it shows the error as I said, no class definition found